# LINQ Get Grouped ID by condition

Tags: linq, group-by, contains

Hi I have a List so:

```
A    1
A    2
A    3
A    4
B    1
B    2
C    1
```

I want to select the letter that contains AT LEAST these 3 numbers: 1,2,3

So in this case would be selected the letter A.

Can you help me to write this as LINQ expression?

Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 1):

First, make a collection of the numbers you require.

```
var required = new[] { 1, 2, 3 };
```

Then, group your pairings by letter.

```
var groupedPairings = pairings.GroupBy(p => Letter, p => Number);
```

Then, discard those pairings that don't have your three required items. (The logic here is "take the collection of required items, remove anything in the group, and make sure there is nothing left".)

```
var groupsWithRequired = groupedPairings
    .Where(g => !required.Except(g).Any());
```

Now, if you just want the letters, you can simply do

```
var lettersWithRequired = groupsWithRequired.Select(g => g.Key);
```

or if you want a dictionary mapping from the letter to its collection of numbers, you can do

```
var dictionary = groupsWithRequired.ToDictionary(g => g.Key, g => g.ToArray());
var numbersForA = dictionary["A"]; // = {1, 2, 3, 4}
```

Answer (score 0):

You could try this, although I don't feel it's the best answer:

```
var items = new List<Item>{ 
    new Item{Name="A", Value=1},
    new Item{Name="A", Value=2},
    new Item{Name="A", Value=3},
    new Item{Name="A", Value=3},
    new Item{Name="A", Value=4},
    new Item{Name="B", Value=1},
    new Item{Name="B", Value=2},
    new Item{Name="C", Value=1},
};

var values = new List<int>{1,2,3};

var query = items.GroupBy (i => i.Name)
                 .Where (i => i.Select (x => x.Value)
                               .Intersect(values).Count() == values.Count)
                 .Select (i => i.Key);
```

Where

```
class Item{
    public string Name{get;set;}
    public int Value{get;set;}
}
```